# Spring Oauth2, trying to get access_token during user Registration api call, without getting it through oauth/token endpoint

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

Okay so I have an Mobile to Spring Java API Rest stack.  I have implemented the Oauth2 security as described in the spring guide https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html.  I use the standard oauth/token endpoint for the user to login with credentials.  Since we are trying to consolidate calls the mobile is making to the API, we want to put an access_token object in the response of the registration/step2 endpoint (at this point the users credentials and password has been persisted to the DB).  I am not sure what code I need to add to get an access_token this way?

I know I have to make some DefaultTokenRequest with some params to the TokenGranter. Here is some of my config:

```
<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<!-- Default authentication manager -->
<!--<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">-->
<!--<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='userService' />-->
<!--<security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />-->
<!--</security:authentication-manager>-->


<!--New authentication manager  -->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='userService' />
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.special.authenticationProvider" >
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
    <property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource" />
</beans:bean>


<bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetailsService" />
</bean>

<!-- Authentication manager for OAUTH token request endpoint -->
<security:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- oauth token storage -->
<bean id="oauthDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore"
      class="com.special.JdbcTokenStoreUserID">
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStoreCore"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="oauthDataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetailsService" />
    <property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="customTokenEnhancer" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>
<bean id="customTokenEnhancer" class="com.special.CustomTokenEnhancer"></bean>
```